# How to Force Selenium InternetExplorerDriver to move past initial page timeout

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I'm using the 32 bit, version 3.14 version of the IEDriverServer.
I'm using IE v11 and have turned on protected mode in all zones.
I have the following code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            EnableNativeEvents = false,
            IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
            EnsureCleanSession = true,
            ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
        };

        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(<path to IEDriverServer>, options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:60448/Account/Login");
    }
  }
}
```

- When I run the console app, I get a console telling me the IEDriverServer version and what port it is listening on.
- I see an IE dialog pop up that is deleting the browser cache and history.
- Then IE v11 opens up with `localhost:<whatever port the IEDriverServer is listening on>`
- In the browser, there is the text: `This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.`
- A minute later, Visual Studio shows me this exception:

  `The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
  http://localhost:<whatever port the console said the driver was listening on>/session timed out after 60 seconds.`

The exception is happening on the line that instantiates the `new InternetExplorerDriver` even though I see an open instance of IE and it is displaying the page that is supposedly not responding.

Please help if you know how to get past this line.

Comment: For testing purpose, Try to remove the options parameter and try to create the object of the driver. Than try to replace your URL with the URL of any other site to check whether it is opening it or not. If it opens the page than try to make a test with each option to check whether any one of them creating this issue or not.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried all that first. It was only with the options I have now that I could even get it to automatically open IE. The code never makes it to the line where it navigates to my site. The exception is always thrown on the previous line so it doesn't matter what I put in for the website.

Comment: For a testing purpose, Can you try to make a test after turning off the protected mode? Let us know about the testing result. I also suggest you to run the code on other machine to check whether it generates similar error or it can work without any issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't make it clear that I've tested with protected mode off in all areas and again with protected mode on in all areas and I get the same result either way. I will try my code on another computer that is not on my client's network. Because so far, I've tested on three different computers but because the IT department has locked down making certain changes to IE, I've had to set the values using Registry hacks. I will test on my personal computer where I have full control and see if it works.

Comment: You can let us know about your testing result on other machine. We will try to provide further suggestions, If needed.